# how to add two flavors of objects in one list using generics?

Tags: java

I am new to Java and have small doubt. Consider this case:

> I have Fruit class, this is super class, and two subclasses, those are Apple and Orange. Now I want to keep these two types of objects, into one list object, using Generics concept.

Comment: Go through the [Generics tutorial at Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Comment: maybe if you had a list of type: `Fruit` ...

Comment: I think the downvoters are being unnecessarily harsh :(.  But do read the tutorial above, and be sure to upvote and accept Admit's response (if it helped).

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Fruit> fruits  = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
fruits.add(new Apple());
fruits.add(new Orange());
```

But be prepared that `fruits.get(0)` will return `Fruit` object and learn more about generics.